# How to terminate GUI in SunOS from a shell-script

Tags: solaris, gui

How to terminate GUI in SunOS from a shell-script running it from the terminal.

Comment: I have no clue on what command to use on Solaris and I don't have the machine available,in Ubuntu I found `sudo stop lightdm`

Comment: You should state the SunOS (Solaris) version used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `svcadm` commands:

**Disable the cde-login service:**

```
svcadm disable svc:/application/graphical-login/cde-login:default
```

**Enable it back:**

```
svcadm enable svc:/application/graphical-login/cde-login:default
```

Or, if you want to do it old school:

**Disable:**

```
/usr/dt/bin/dtconfig -d
```

**Enable:**

```
/usr/dt/bin/dtconfig -e
```

Comment: On Solaris 11 & later, cde-login has been replaced by gdm, so it would be `svcadm disable gdm` and `svcadm enable gdm` instead.

Comment: Yup, but we don't have more details about Solaris version, at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's been ages since the last time I had a SunOS workstation I would imagine that the GUI is typically part of the default runlevel 3 and changing to runlevel 2 would disable the GUI:

```
telinit 2
```

The GUI (possibly Xorg)  is most likely a service you can disable with `svcadm  disable <FMRI>`  The list of possble services can be found with `svcs -a`.

Comment: Nope, when Solaris used runlevels (prior to the switch to SMF in Solaris 10), the GUI was started in runlevel 2, as part of the "local system services" -- runlevel 3 was for running servers for other systems to connect to.